# Metric space of graphs

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, algebraic-graph-theory

I am looking for references discussing the space of graphs G=(V,E), attempts at definition of distance between graphs, proximity, small (differential) neighborhoods of distinct graphs (different number of vertices in particular), transformations etc., references akin to this paper:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X16303067

I am finding the discussion and references on space of graphs (w distinct number of nodes) surprisingly illusive. Suggestions, or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It's not a bad question, but some of your terminology is very much unclear: What do you mean by "proximity", "differential" neighborhoods, what "transformations" are you talking about? Also, you should specify if you are interested in finite or infinite graphs.

Comment: Thank you MK, please excuse my lack of precision and formalism which indeed is the case. I am primarily looking for a metric space with which to describe graphs, where a distance can be defined between two graphs: G(V1,E1) and G(V2,E2) and in particular a way to define incremental changes/transformations between two graphs defined by addition of a single new node to a graph (G2  = G1 + one additional node). G2= G1 + Delta(G) where Delta(G) represents conceptually, the addition of a single node - all referring to"finite" graphs here.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space_(mathematics)#Moduli_space) and see if this is what you have in mind. The trick is to include "metric graphs" to the discussion. The standard graphs become elements of the space when every edge is declared to have unit length.

Comment: Thank you MK, useful additional reference for sure, but I can't lock into the intuition I am looking for especially with variable number of nodes. I am starting to wonder if the answer lies outside of finite graphs. Looking for metric space of finite dim graphs with variable "nodes" seems to be the dilemma - almost akin to looking for a metric vector space in which vectors are of different dimensions? It seems with finite dimensional graphs, the number of nodes would determine the natural dimension of the space. Then how do we even talk about dist. between vectors of different dimensions?